# Is there a simple way of extracting the topic outline of a Google Docs document?

Tags: google-docs

I'd like to copy the contents of a Google Docs automatic topics outline, the titles/headings that can be shown on the left of a document for navigation.

I'd like to manually edit it, use it as the basis for a checklist/progress tracking document.

Comment: This question doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @Rubén, it was so much of a practical, detailed question, albeit simple, that it elicited a perfectly good and helpful asnwer. It helped me and could help others. The answer even has some other upvotes.

Comment: @Rubén, assuming I've read the books you threw at the OP, how specifically do you think I could help improve the OP's question, given that it was good enough to get a relevant and useful response?

Comment: @LucianoRamalho Welcome to [webapps.se]. Try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pretty much do this by inserting a table of contents, and copying that.

I.e. the Google Docs "Insert" menu has "Table of contents" entry, and its "With blue links" choice is the same as the topic outline, except that when the structure of your document changes, you need to manually update the table of contents by clicking it and then clicking the refresh icon.

Comment: Thank you! I missed this, perfect solution.